# REST API table.export to Google Drive

Tags: google-earth-engine, rest

I tried to export a table data to google drive with REST API. The response showed succeeded but I didn't see the file in my Google Drive folder. When I tried export to Google Cloud, it worked. I don't know why it didn't export to drive.

The code is :

```py
url = 'https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1beta/projects/{}/table:export'
 # 'serialized' is same variable provided by computed Tables example in GEE website https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/Earth_Engine_REST_API_compute_table?hl=en
response = session.post(
  url = url.format(PROJECT),
  data = json.dumps({ 'expression': serialized,      
      'description': 'a test for table export to drive',      
      'requestId': 'test1',
      'maxErrorMeters': 1,  
      'maxVertices' : 2147483646,            
      'fileExportOptions': {
        'fileFormat': 'TF_RECORD_TABLE',
        'driveDestination': { 
          'folder' : 'test',    
          'filenamePrefix': 'a01',
          },
        },
    })
)
```

Is there a way to export data to Drive?